# Как отредактировать шаблон в Typo3?

Tags: веб-программирование

Суть такая. Есть некий сайт и там нужно поменять телефоны, методом тыка нашли телефоны в /fileadmin/templates/index.html

Ну и этот шаблон много где фигурирует. Редактируем файл через ФТП (меняем только телефоны), заливаем на сервер. Сайт перестает работать, загружается пустой body.

Если пересохранить в windows-1251, то работает, но с кракозябрами, а в utf-8 вообще не работает, но если вернуть все как было до редактирования, то снова работает.

В чем может быть дело? Как вообще изменять шаблоны в TYPO3?